# Story about enhanced gladiators

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I recall reading a short story in which a prisoner meets several physically enhanced gladiators (or possibly, long-term prisoners in some survival-type prison).

Specifically, one of them had a triple jointed arm that (she?) could crack like a whip, and knuckles that could dent steel.  The other arm was double jointed and might have been outfitted with a blade.

This would have been from the golden age of science fiction, not anything recent.

Comment: By "Golden Age" you mean roughly 1937–1950? Do you remember anything else in the story? The prison was on earth or another planet? The prisoner was human, male or female? enhanced? What was he in for? What happens in the story? Does the prisoner die? Does he escape? Does he get in a fight with the prisoner with enhanced arms?

Comment: Also, where are you likely to have read it? In an anthology, a magazine, online?

Comment: My edit did not go through, even though I've waited a couple of days.  I really don't remember much about it other than the description of the one gladiator.  I think the protagonist was a male human, newbie gladiator, who greets the others as neutrals because he might have to fight them.  He might actually fight the triple-joined gladiator and win.

Comment: As for time frame and source, it was probably an anthology from the 60s-70s.